# CSS, height makes the border color change

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

Sometimes CSS acts weird in chrome, the difference between the two divs are only the height parameter, but as a result: the border color is different.

```css
body {
background: black;
}

#div1 {
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 41px;
    width: 100px;
    transform: rotateZ(270deg);
    transform-origin: right;
}

#div2 {
    border: 1px solid white;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100px;
    transform: rotateZ(270deg);
    transform-origin: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="div1">

</div>

<br><br><br><br><br><br>

<div id="div2">

</div>
```

PS : I am working under chrome with 100% zoom

result : [image: picture]

Comment: I see no difference whatsoever.

Comment: I will post a picture

Comment: Anti-aliasing. The center of rotation is at a half pixel vertically for the first one, so it divides the border among two pixels. If you change the transform-origin to `right bottom` (or any coordinate that is on a whole pixel value) the differences go away.

Comment: a rendering issue, you will see a different result for odd and even values

Comment: @TemaniAfif You right do you have a reason why it happens?

Comment: I cant add an image, but the borders look the same on both divs, suggest you to check on another device/screen

Comment: @לבנימלכה as said by Mr Lister it's probably an anti aliasing due to how the transform is cacluated .. the browser isn't clever enough to know that rotate(270deg) will be at the end another non-rotated rectangle

Comment: Maybe you should update the question with which environments this affects. I can see the problem on Windows with a non-Retina monitor in Firefox and Chrome, but not in Edge or IE11.

Comment: Same under Linux, so I think only people with high-resolution displays can't see it.

Comment: Try to use `even numbers` for everything, so that avoid different issue like this. P.S. your `div1` has 41px

Comment: Maybe because of the transformation your border is slightly blurred and it causes the color change of the border

Answer (score 1):

This is in fact an anti aliasing issue.
The 1px border is in between two pixels, resulting in this grey looking color.

To visualize this I have taken a screenshot for you, zoomed in and put a grid over it:

[image]

Keep that in mind when transforming objects.